# The topic of wholesale energy markets

Tags: discussion, tags

I am interested in posting some questions on EE.SE on the topic of wholesale electricity markets as opposed to Economics.SE

This topic is taught in many 400-level undergrad EE degrees that have a concentration in large scale power distribution. If this is acceptable would anyone support the creation of an `energy-markets` tag to better categorize these kinds of questions? Posting these questions in the Economics.SE while logical isolates much of the EE community's knowledge that would be extremely useful at arriving at accurate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post any question as long as it follows these guidelines:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Also don't ask for help finding resources or information
https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Another thing to consult would be this meta for other guidelines

However, YMMV on the subject matter, while the site says electrical engineering, most people here follow the circuits branch of electrical engineering. Questions on the price of electricity is off topic, asking about how an aspect of the grid or a power generation facility works is not off topic but there are few with expertise in that area. I'd say that 80%-90% are circuits engineers or digital engineers.